# No Power at All / Key Stuck in Ignition 2009 cobalt

Tags: electrical

went to start my Cobalt, turned the keys on, power flashed on for a second and then everything went out and keys got stuck in the ignition.

Answer (score 0):

Happens A lot when you drive automatic transmission cars. What works for me in such situations is the following. Open the hood remove the positive cable from batter then put it back up, go in car turn to ignition, but not to spin the engine, move your gear shift to drive then back to P, then turn it back and get it out.

That happens when you have no power or some electrical problem.
If the above doesn't help get other battery from a friend it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The key not turning off on GM vehicles with low/dead battery is a normal function of the car. Either charge or replace the battery then turn the key to crank and back to off to remove. You can also remove the shroud around steering wheel and press the release button underneath the ignition to turn the key switch fully off and remove key.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I was thinking to mention the release button myself - is that not correct?

Comment: The information is correct. I guess it is more of a side effect then a function. The problem is caused by the safety mechanism that prevents you from turning your ignition to lock (also triggering the wheel lock) while the car is in motion. It needs to sense the shifter is in PARK to release. All cars have this safety feature. GM on some of their models designed this solenoid to be locked in its normal state and to release when powered. The key getting stuck when ever there is a low/dead battery is its side effect because this solenoid is preventing the switch from being turned fully to lock.